# ¿Como configuro mi DNS en hostinger?

Tags: web, hosting, dns

Tengo un sitio web en Hostinger que cargue hace unos 25 días, el dominio funcionaba bien y sin ningún problema, deje de ingresar como por 8 días y ahora que ingreso me muestra error en el DNS al cargar la pagina (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN) [image: Mensaje al ingresar al dominio]

Comment: Segun veo ya se han propagado los cambios de DNS... ¿te funciona bien ahora todo?  Si mi respuesta satiface tu pregunta deberias marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede la pregunta pendiente para siempre. Pulsa este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para aprender a aceptar respuestas, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Advertencia**: Los datos de esta respuesta estan falseados y/o enmascarados para conservar la privacidad del dominio e ips. La IP resultante se muestra como **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx** de forma expresa.

---

Tienes un problema en los **Name Servers** de tu registrador de dominio, donde mediante una instrucción `whois midominio.com` aparece esto:

```
Name Server: midominio.com
Name Server: ns2.dns-ejemplo.com
```

Eso indica que tus servidores de nombres son esos dos a nivel de registrador de dominio (allí donde comprastes ese nombre), pero si intentamos consultarlos mediante la instrucción `dig` uno de ellos falla:

```
$ dig midominio.com @midominio.com +short

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> midominio.com @midominio.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Y si consultamos al otro nos devuelve correctamente la información:

```
$ dig midominio.com @ns2.dns-ejemplo.com +short
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Eso tiene toda la pinta de ser el problema, porque cuando consultamos cualquier dominio en Internet, nuestras peticiones se pueden dirigir a cualquiera de esos dos Name Server (pueden haber más, pero normalmente son dos), y teóricamente si uno falla la petición salta al otro, pero no siempre, y en este caso tu no puedes conectarte porque ha fallado la petición, seguramente porque dicha petición tan solo se ha basado en el Name Server que falla.

Aprovechando eso vamos a consultar los registros NS del que está funcionando, a ver si vemos nada raro, y vemos que nos devuelve esto:

```
$ dig midominio.com NS @ns2.dns-ejemplo.com +short
ns1.dns-ejemplo.com.
ns2.dns-ejemplo.com.
```

y para terminar de delimitar el problema, vamos a consultar al primero de ellos, que no aparece en el `whois` anterior, si realmente contiene los mismos datos e información:

```
$ dig midominio.com NS @ns1.dns-ejemplo.com +short
ns1.dns-ejemplo.com.
ns2.dns-ejemplo.com.
$ dig midominio.com @ns1.dns-ejemplo.com +short
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Visto esto podemos deducir tres cosas:

1. Uno de los Name Server usado en el `whois` no contesta las peticiones
2. En el otro Name Server la información es distinta, y aparece otro Name Server distinto al que no contesta
3. El Name Server que aparece en el punto 2 como distinto vemos que también contesta adecuadamente las peticiones

Y con esa información concluimos que hay que acudir al sitio web donde tengamos un panel de administración del dominio donde fue registrado (en su registrador, o sea, donde se compró el nombre de dominio) y modificar sus Name Server para que sean los correctos, sustituyendo este:

```
midominio.com
```

por este:

```
ns1.dns-ejemplo.com
```

y guardar los cambios.

Si no se dispone de dicho acceso, hay que contactar con el vendedor del dominio y decirle que hay que realizar el cambio. **Recuerda** que tienes que sustituir la cadena **dns-ejemplo.com** por la correspondiente a tu dominio real, el cual puedes consultar via web en este [enlace](https://who.is/) poniendo el nombre de dominio real, y cuando devuelva la información, fijarte en los datos que aparecen bajo el título: *Name Servers*.

Una vez realizado el cambio se inicia lo que se denomina la "propagación" de dichos cambios, que viene delimitada por varios factores, siendo el TTL uno de los importantes, pero tambien los tiempos de refresco de cache propios de cada servidor de nombres encadenado donde estemos consultando la información desde nuestros dispositivos, llegando a tardar un máximo de 48 horas en propagarse en todo el mundo dicho cambio. Es decir, en otras palabras, no es immediato, y la media en su propagación acostumbra a estar entre 4 y 48 horas, y no es una propagación idéntica en todas la redes y dispositivos, es decir, te puede funcionar desde Tokio, pero no aun desde Córdova y debes seguir esperando hasta un máximo de 48 horas, y si con eso no ha funcionado revisar los cambios porque alguno estará mal hecho.