# ¿Cómo puedo configurar mi sitio web para que este a la disposición de otros ISP?

Tags: dns, host

Tengo un sitio web el cual esta alojado en en un servicio que contrate de host. El detalle esta, en que  hace unos días si era accesible desde cualquier ISP. Hace 2 días, dejo de funcionar y ahora solo es accesible desde un SIP especifico, ya que al ingresar desde otro la pagina no carga.

Comment: No repitas preguntas. Si no has entendido [mi respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516625/como-configuro-mi-dns-en-hostinger) me preguntas en los comentarios y te ayudo. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para entender como funciona este sitio y como deben ser las preguntas.

Comment: El inconveniente anterior ya lo solucione pues antes no cargaba desde ningún proveedor, ahora, desde cierto ISP si toma la pagina, pero desde otro no.

Comment: Pues diria que no has entendido mi respuesta ni tampoco has hecho lo que te he dicho en la misma. ¿Donde comprastes el dominio? (no me contestes, es retorica) Pues ves al sitio donde lo comprastes, que seguramente tienen un panel para acceder, y mira las propiedades de tu dominio, y cambia el name server (servidor de nombres) que apunta a tu web y pon este: **ns1.dns-parking.com**.  Hasta que no lo hagas te aseguro que no te a funcionar en todas partes, solo a ratos en algunas, de forma aleatoria ademas.

Comment: Si no recuerdas haber hecho ese cambio recientemente (o alguien que pudiera hacerlo sin querer) entonces el problema puede estar en que efectivamente el servidor donde esta alojada tu web tambien tiene servidor DNS, pero que ahora mismo no funciona y esta caido, y por eso no responde a las peticiones (pero eso me lo tienes que confirmar tu, pues no se si estas en un cpanel, plesk, dedicado o que en tu web)

Comment: Justamente he cambiado los nombres,  pero el inconveniente persiste, note que al configurar manualmente el DNS el dispositivo al de Google (8.8.8.8) este si puede ingresar, pero al no estarlo no y esto sucede solo con un determinado ISP, ya que hay otro el cual si permite ingresar sin configurar nada adicional. Leí sobre la propagación de DNS's, esperaré las 48 horas, si luego de ello no funciona, contactare a soporte. Muchas gracias  por tu apoyo!

Comment: Vale, ahora esta bien. Veo que has puesto 4, je. He comprobado y todos van bien, asi que no tendras problema cuando la propagacion termine. Tu estate tranquilo y ya veras como se arregla a nivel global en un máximo de 48 horas.

Comment: En esta web ya aparece bien propagado en muchas partes: https://dnschecker.org  (pon tu nombre de dominio y selecciona NS y veras que casi todos ya estan usando los nuevos)